# Django SocialAuth / Django AllAuth: How to save user details into user profile upon login with Facebook if Account does not exist?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-allauth, python-social-auth

Django SocialAuth / Django AllAuth: How to save user details into user profile upon login with Facebook if Account does not exist?

I have set up Django SocialAuth and AllAuth into my project for login using Facebook.

This is my Profile model.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    profile_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)

    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

How do I get these details when a new user logs in and save them to profile model?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, if you are using django social auth package, you can set-up extra custom pipeline function.

https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html